# In array filter, How to make system allow 0

Tags: php, arrays

`$data` is multidimensional array, This array contain different type of values

`number`, `character`, `float`, `empty`,`Boolean`

Here I want to filter just empty, but below function filtering the 0, false as well, please suggest one quick solution please.

```
$data = array_map('array_filter',$data);

$data = array_filter($data,function($a){return $a!='';});
```

above both sample does not full fill the requirement.

```
array ('school'=>array('key1'=>abc,'key2'=>1,'key3'=>0,'key4'=>,'key5'=>false))
```

Comment: be careful with `!=` and `!==`

Comment: can you show me your array?

Comment: try `$myarray = array_filter($myarray, 'strlen');`

Comment: attached sample array

Comment: @ChetanAmeta returning entire array as empty

Comment: You need to use it like as `$myarray = array_filter($data['school'],function($a){return $a!='';});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as simply instead of `$data` to `$data['school']`

```
$data['school'] = array_filter($data['school'], function($a) {
    return $a != '';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = array_filter($data,function($a){return ($a!=='' && is_null($a)===false );});
```

Comment: You are correct to use the triple (!==) but it looks like he wants to remove NULL's too. Maybe I am wrong but 'key4' seems to be the target here.

Comment: i added checking for null too, there was a massive edit to the main-post since my answer

Answer (score 0):

use a custom function because native php function will treat '0' and 'false' as empty:

```
function array_non_empty_items($input) {
    // If it is an element, then just return it.
    if (!is_array($input)) {
        return $input;
    }

    $non_empty_items = array();

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        // Ignore empty cells
        if($value !== '') {
            // Use recursion to evaluate cells.
            $non_empty_items[$key] = array_non_empty_items($value);
        }
    }

    // Finally returns the array without empty items.
    return $non_empty_items;
}
```